# How to check multiple radio buttons at a time in asp.net dekstop application?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I am making a form in which I have 2 radio buttons rows. I checked radio button I one row, but when I checked radio button in 2nd row first one unchecked. and I have put condition on radio button that on check textfield.enabled should be true.. this condition is also not working...

```
public partial class EntryForm : Form
{

    public EntryForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (OfferReceived.Checked == true || CAS.Checked == true)
        {
            TxtRefNo.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void TxtVfs_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
}
```

So, where do I have to put this condition?

Comment: Wait, what? Is this WinForms or ASP .NET? :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add each radio button group (or row) in its own container (use a Panel, a TableLayoutPanel or something similar). This way, you can have a radio button selected from each group.

Otherwise, there should not be more than one radio button selected at a time in each group; that's the whole point of a radio button.

Comment: U mean to say that I should put radio buttons in first row in a panel? Then how will I apply condition on these? like panel.rd1.checked = true?? I have put radio button in a panel but above mention condition is not working

Comment: @TouseefKhan: what do you mean by "it's not working"? By the way, when accessing the radio buttons in the panel, you have to access them directly, like so: `rd.checked = true`, not `panel.rd1.Checked = true`

Comment: @alex putting in panel first issue has resolved. but condition is not working.. Am I putting it in wrong place?  I have put it in form load and then in class as well... but no avail

Comment: @TouseefKhan: is it a condition? If it is, use equality comparison (`==`), not assignment (`=`).

Comment: yes on using = I get warning,,that assignment in conditional expression is always constant,, did u mean to use == instead of =?

Comment: @TouseefKhan: Well, do what it says, use ==. That's how you compare 2 values.

Comment: @TouseefKhan: it's strange, because I tried the same thing before posting my answer and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Radio Buttons are mutually exclusive. If you want multi-selection use Check Boxes instead.